# I want to middle the text in the slider, though I resize it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have used position absolute to center the text within the slider, but when I resize it the text are not remain as center position. How to fix that?

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/138944745/bootstrap_lambdatest/index.html

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add This to your class `.slider_text`:

```
left:0;
right:0;
margin:0 auto;
text-align: center;
```

Comment: Thanks Maharkus. It's works.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I'll try it:

```
.slider_header > h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

For me this is ok.